# How can I count users using only one provider?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello I'm practicing and trying to do a fidelity list for some service providers, so I need an object like this:

```
object = {
   providerName: NumberOfUsersWithServiceOnly 
   providerName: NumberOfUsersWithServiceOnly
   providerName: NumberOfUsersWithServiceOnly
   providerName: NumberOfUsersWithServiceOnly
}
```

I have the object with the names of each provider but I need the value pair for each and that's the number of users who only have that provider.

So far I only have these arrays:

```
const services = [
    { userid: 1, providerId: 1, balance: 250000 },
    { userid: 4, providerId: 3, balance: 280900 },
    { userid: 6, providerId: 3, balance: 31000 },
    { userid: 2, providerId: 2, balance: 58600 },
    { userid: 3, providerId: 1, balance: 13000 },
    { userid: 5, providerId: 2, balance: 5000 },
    { userid: 3, providerId: 3, balance: 59900 },
    { userid: 7, providerId: 3, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 7, providerId: 2, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 4, providerId: 1, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 6, providerId: 3, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 2, providerId: 2, balance: 9500 }
]

const providers = [
    { id: 1, name: Netflix },
    { id: 2, name: Comcast },
    { id: 3, name: Verizon }
]

let result= {};
    providers.forEach(provider=> {
       result[provider.name] = [];
})
```

In this example the output I'm looking for would be:

```
result = {
    Netflix: 1, // only 1 user has only this service
    Comcast: 3, // only 1 user has only this service
    Verizon: 2, // 3 users have only this service
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create an object that keeps track of how many services a user has subscribed to. Then, using that mapping, you can compute how many users each service has that have subscribed to only that service.

```js
const services = [
    { userid: 1, providerId: 1, balance: 250000 },
    { userid: 4, providerId: 3, balance: 280900 },
    { userid: 6, providerId: 3, balance: 31000 },
    { userid: 2, providerId: 2, balance: 58600 },
    { userid: 3, providerId: 1, balance: 13000 },
    { userid: 5, providerId: 2, balance: 5000 },
    { userid: 3, providerId: 3, balance: 59900 },
    { userid: 7, providerId: 3, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 7, providerId: 2, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 4, providerId: 1, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 6, providerId: 3, balance: 9500 },
    { userid: 2, providerId: 2, balance: 9500 }
];

const providers = [
    { id: 1, name: "Netflix" },
    { id: 2, name: "Comcast" },
    { id: 3, name: "Verizon" }
];

const userServiceCount = services.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.userid] = acc[curr.userid] || new Set();
  acc[curr.userid].add(curr.providerId);
  return acc;
}, {});
// Object.entries(userServiceCount).forEach(([k, v]) => console.log(k, Array.from(v)));

const result = providers.reduce((acc, {id, name}) => {
  acc[name] = Object.values(userServiceCount).filter(s => s.has(id) && s.size === 1).length
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
  const services = [
        { userid: 1, providerId: 1, amount: 250000 },
        { userid: 4, providerId: 3, amount: 280900 },
        { userid: 6, providerId: 3, amount: 31000 },
        { userid: 2, providerId: 2, amount: 58600 },
        { userid: 3, providerId: 1, amount: 13000 },
        { userid: 5, providerId: 2, amount: 5000 },
        { userid: 3, providerId: 3, amount: 59900 },
        { userid: 7, providerId: 3, amount: 9500 }
    ]

    const providers = [
        { id: 1, name: "Netflix" },
        { id: 2, name: "Comcast" },
        { id: 3, name: "Verizon" }
    ]

    const result = providers.reduce((a,res) => ( a[res.name] = services.filter(ele => ele.providerId === res.id).length - 1, a), {});

     
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: it's wrong the output should be result = {
    Netflix: 1, // only 1 user has only this service
    Comcast: 3, // only 1 user has only this service
    Verizon: 2, // 3 users have only this service
}

Comment: @Noderjs, more explanation plz